# Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name when load keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to load model's checkpoint from Colab on my local machine but got an error:

```
TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name
```

As for optimizer call it looks like this:

```
# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-5),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I used exactly the same code i used in Colab (it worked there)

Keras version - 2.2.4

TensorFlow - 1.13.1

The same problem occurs if i try to load model.h5
I also tried to load the model in Rstudio but still get the same error

More detailed error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-d8e38e577b3d>", line 95, in <module>
    model = keras.models.load_model("C:/Users/diu/Documents/Python/Checkpoints/cp.ckpt")

  File "C:\Users\diu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\saving.py", line 249, in load_model
    optimizer_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)

  File "C:\Users\diu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 838, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='optimizer')

  File "C:\Users\diu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 194, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(cls_config)

  File "C:\Users\diu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 159, in from_config
    return cls(**config)

  File "C:\Users\diu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 471, in __init__
    super(Adam, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\diu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py", line 68, in __init__
    'passed to optimizer: ' + str(k))

TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name
```

Comment: Are you mixing imports from keras and tf.keras?

Comment: Seems that you are right.. it worked in Colab so i thought no problem should appear on local machine. Will try tf model import

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in syntax.

Colab was ok with:

```
model = keras.models.load_model("drive/My Drive/Models/my_model.h5")
```

In Spyder i was able to load model weights with line :

```
model.load_weights("~/Python/Model/my_model.h5")
```

P.S. code above was executed after defining the model and optimizer

Comment: Please elaborate the answer so others can easily understand your method.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Colab uses tensorflow 2.x and in your machine you have tensorflow 1.x. Therefore there is mismatch.

You can do this,

In your local machine,

```
import tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("my_model.h5", compile = False)
```

Hope, This works.